# How to bind to right object to this in this case?

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

My question is how to correctly point 'this' to the right Object for last 2 lines. I understand 'this' points to window now. How to correct them to the right one.

```
function Person(first, last, age) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype = {
    getFullName: function() {
        alert(this.first + ' ' + this.last);
    },
    greet: function(other) {
        alert("Hi " + other.first + ", I'm " + this.first + ".");
    }
};
var elodie = new Person('Elodie', 'Jaubert', 27);
var christophe = new Person('Christophe', 'Porteneuve', 30);

function times(n, fx, arg) {
    for (var index = 0; index < n; ++index) {
        fx(arg);
    }
}
times(3, christophe.greet, elodie); // => Three times "Hi Elodie, I'm undefined."
times(1, elodie.getFullName ); // => "undefined undefined"
```

Comment: Did you try `times(3, christophe.greet.bind(christophe), elodie);`?

Comment: Hi Josh, is there a way to use call/apply?

Comment: A function's *this* is set by how you call it, or *bind*. So call the function in a way that sets its *this* to the value you want.

Comment: If you want to invoke the greet function on christophe with `this` as the christophe object using `call`, you could do  `christophe.greet.call(christophe, elodie)`

Comment: Do you have to use prototype? A closure may work better for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'd love to know how u can write it in a Closure way. I just started to learn javascript , anything would help.

Answer (score 2):

Refactor your times function like this:

```
function times(n, obj, fx, arg) {
    for (var index = 0; index < n; ++index) {
        obj[fx](arg);
    }
}
times(3, christophe, "greet", elodie);
times(1, elodie, "getFullName" );
```

working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/acatkk53/

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**`Function.prototype.bind`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), like Josh's advice (requires IE9 and above):

```
times(3, christophe.greet.bind(christophe), elodie);
times(1, elodie.getFullName.bind(elodie));
```

There's also a `bind` [**polyfill**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill) for IE8-.

Or, you could go with `Function.prototype.call`, you'll need to modify the `times` function:

```
function times(n, fx, subjective, objective) {
    for (var index = 0; index < n; ++index) {
        fx.call(subjective, objective);
    }
}

times(3, christophe.greet, christophe, elodie);
times(1, elodie.getFullName, elodie);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this ,

```
function Person(first, last, age) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype = {
    getFullName: function() {
        alert(this.first + ' ' + this.last);
    },
    greet: function(other) {
        alert("Hi " + other.first + ", I'm " + this.first + ".");
    }
};
var elodie = new Person('Elodie', 'Jaubert', 27);
var christophe = new Person('Christophe', 'Porteneuve', 30);

function times(n, fx, self, arg) {
    for (var index = 0; index < n; ++index) {
        fx.call(self,arg);
    }
}
times(3, christophe.greet, christophe , elodie); 
times(1, elodie.getFullName, christophe );
```